# AngularJS - ng-grid sliding window - table not updating from array change

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to use ng-grid with a sliding window of 100 records. The data is coming in realtime via signalR and every message trigger the following method:

```
 onNewTrades(records) {
        console.log("onNewRecord", records);

        if (connectionStopped) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

            if ($scope.recordsData.length > maxRecordsInTable)
                $scope.recordsData.pop();

            $scope.recordsData.unshift({
                t: new Date(records[i][0]),
                p: records[i][1],           
                a: records[i][2]            
            });
        }      
    }
```

I have a threshold of 100 `maxRecordsInTable` before I start popping items off the end (before adding the new message to the front)

However, when it reaches my threshold the table simple stops updating. Strangely though, if I set a breakpoint on unshift(), the table does update with every "continue".

I suspect it's some kind of angular timing issue? I tried using $timeout()
Or may when I pop() and unshift() at the same time it doesn't pick up a change in the array?  I tried using $apply() (error already in digest cycle)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be happening here.

First of all, if `onNewTrade` is using an external, non-angular, library making xhr requests outside of angular's framework (i.e. not using `$http` or `$resource`), you have to call `$scope.$apply(function(){ })` around the code you want the scope's digest to know about.  That part's not clear from what you've provided. *edit*: Read more about [when to use $scope.$apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

Second, angular's digest phase does a minimum of two passes (first to make changes, second to make sure there are no more changes). It does at most 10 passes by default. If angular evaluates the scope 10 times and it is not consistent, it gives up. [see documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest). It does this because you can have multiple watch functions where one watch affects the scope higher in the hierarchy, which makes changes and affects the same watch.. basically causing an evented infinite loop.  Do you see a console error about '10 $digest iterations, aborting!' or something similar?

There are a couple of other questionable things:

- is `onNewRecord` asynchronous? If so, I would doubt `connectionStopped` is being done correctly. You could be returning early. Because you say a breakpoint shows values on unshift, its probably not the cause of this issue (and most likely missing $scope.$apply is the problem), but I'd rethink this code.
- Your function is `onNewTrade(records)`, but you log `onNewRecord(record)`. If you have nested variables here, make sure you haven't excluded code that may contain typos (e.g. `record` instead of `records`). You might be working on an unexpected object.